# How to use a two dimensional array to store classes?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create a map in swift (two-dimensional) containing a CLASS on each field (groundType, height, visible etc).

Have found nothing how to reallize this... Most examples only have simple Int or Boolean as content.

That I can access like:

```
let currentField = field[x,y].height()
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example creating a `5 X 3` multidimensional array to hold classes of type `Field`:

```
class Field {
    init (groundType: String, height: Double, visible: Bool) {
        self.groundType = groundType
        self.height = height
        self.visible = visible
    }

    var groundType: String
    var height: Double
    var visible: Bool
}

// A two-dimensional array is just an array of arrays.  Use the Array constructor
// twice to create a 5 by 3 multidimensional array
var fields:[[Field?]] = Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: nil))

fields[4][2] = Field(groundType: "mountain", height: 4300.23, visible: true)

if let height = fields[4][2]?.height {
    println(height)
}
```